# How to remove the Equals,Does not Equal operators from the Adv,Search Property Restrictions

Tags: search, enterprise-search, advanced-search, property-restrictions

Is it possible to remove the **"Equals"** from the dropdown , thats part of property restrictons in advanced search  in SP 2013?

I know we can remove the languages, and add/edit the properties using the xml file .Similarly , can we remove any of the operators like **Equals/No Equals**
from the operator dropdown?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it by editing any of the web part properties. I tried hiding them with a bit of JavaScript in SPO and that worked fine. Your element id may well be different if on-prem...

```
window.onload = function () { 
    var foo = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl40_g_a5766bae_2940_4457_96b6_daed259dab6f_ASB_PS_olb_0");
    foo.options[2].style.display="none";
    foo.options[3].style.display="none";
}
```